# Problem with Rosetta compilation: StructureID has not been declared

Tags: gcc, clang, rosetta

I am trying to compile Rosetta using scons.py script provided by the developers

If I use gcc compilier, I get "error: StructureID has not been declared"

gcc

[image: 1]

If I use clang, I get similar error.

[clang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXngL.png)
Compiler versions are relevant.

If anyone has had a similar issue with Rosetta, please tell me how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

pls follow

> https://www.rosettacommons.org/node/11709
>
> You're using a more recent compiler than existed when Rosetta 3.13 was
> released. Something which worked on the older compilers is no longer
> working.
>
> This has been corrected in more recent weekly releases, but if you
> still want to use Rosetta 3.13, the fix is simple. Simply add the line
>
> ```
> #include <cstdint>
> ```
>
> To the top of the file
> `src/protocols/features/FeaturesReporter.fwd.hh` (After the
> owning_ptr.hh #include line would work.) Then re-launch the Rosetta
> compile process.

let me know if it solves your problem